# PendingIntent sent from a notication

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent

What im trying to accomplish is to send a notification through the notification manager
that once clicked will do something in the application only if its currently running.
i have tried to use:

```
notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, nNotificationCounter, Someintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
```

Which allways caused an exception once trying to use the notify.
I switched to:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.some_notification);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, sTitle);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, sText);
notification.contentView = contentView;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.number = nNotificationCounter;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainWindow.class).setAction(ACTION_RESET_MESSGE_COUNTER);
notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, nNotificationCounter, notificationIntent, 0);
```

and although this code doesn't cause an exception. it doesnt call my BroadcastReceiver which is defined as follows:

```
public class IncomingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RESET_MESSGE_COUNTER)) {
                    System.out.println("GOT THE INTENT");
                    return;
                }

            }
        }
```

and set in the onCreate:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_RESET_MESSGE_COUNTER);
        IncomingReceiver receiver = new IncomingReceiver();
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Does anyone see something wrong with the code?
Or how would i go about to get messages when the notification is clicked, but not create any activity if it isn't already created.

edit: added the intent creation and notification creation.

Thanks,
  Tom

Comment: Make sure `notificationIntent` is set up properly. Since you did not include the code for it here, we can't provide much assistance with it.

Comment: I added all the code, generally is this the way to go about to get a an event only when the acticity is running from a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely not getting the broadcast because you are incorrectly creating your `Intent`. `Intent(Context, Class<?>)` tells the system to create an intent that will 'create' that class. In other words, that intent is directly solely to the hard coded class.  Just use `new Intent(String)` or in your specific case `new Intent(ACTION_RESET_MESSGE_COUNTER)` and you'll create what I call a 'broadcast' intent or what the docs call an 'action' intent. That way the intent will be directed to anyone who is listening for that specific broadcast/action.